# When i post some content to a Page on Facebook with the Graph API, it is only visible to me

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I post some content to page in facebook with Graph API.But this post not published for another people.They dont see all post posted by my app.Only I saw them! What is my problem?

[permisions of user access_token](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zWZXq.png)

```php
// my post's content
post_to_fb_page([
    'message' => 'My message',
    'link' => 'my url'
]);
```

[my post posted by my app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ESUM5.png)

My post posted by my app is public,but it not show for another people, and if i post my facebook account, it is show for all people.

Answer (score 1):

Your App is not public, go to your App dashboard and make sure the switch in the upper right corner is activated and it says "Status: Live". Posts made by Apps that are not live do not show up for regular users.